# Every time I extrude 2 faces, a neon blue line appears, slightly askew, and blue. I need to extrude in a straight line. Help?

Tags: modeling, transforms, extrude

[image][image]I was modelling a robot, with curved legs made of spheres hacked into 8 even pieces. I tried to extrude 2 faces to make part of the joint that connects 2 of the legs (named paddles for some reason), and a blue line keeps popping up, bringing the extruded faces upward slightly, while I try to move the extrusion backwards (-Y axis). Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: I forgot to mention, but the legs are sliced in a way that the top half has 4 parts, and the bottom half has four parts.

Comment: It's probably extruding in the Z direction because you'll see a blue line while youre extruding in that direction. Please add an image of your full Blender screen to your question so that we can see what's going on. In Blender, Window > Save Screenshot and then https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post.

Comment: By default the faces will extrude on their Z axis (face normal axis), if you want to extrude them on another axis, press X or Y or, in case you want to extrude on local axis, double X or double Y

Comment: or press z again to extrude along global z axis. u will see in the upper left corner that it extruding along its normal

Comment: thanks for the help!